# Is the following combination of components valid to function as a desktop computer?

Tags: computer-building

Could someone with more PC building experience than me tell me whether these PC components can cooperate fully as a self-made PC?

- Processor: Intel Core i5-3570K
- Video card: Asus Radeon HD 7870
- Motherboard: Gigabyte GA-Z77-D3H
- RAM: Corsair CMZ16GX3M2A1600C10 Vengeance 16GB 1600MHz CL10 DDR3 (x2)
- Storage: Western Digital WD1002FAEX (x2)
- Display: Samsung S24B300HL
- Sound: Logitech X140
- Chassis: Thermaltake V4 Black Edition VM30001W2Z
- Power supply: Seagate OEM 500W Builder PSU
- Optical drive: Asus DRW-24B1ST

Thanks in advance! (btw, I know 32 GB RAM is unnecessary, but I want to buy it to use as a reserve)

Comment: Hi Gideon! We expect questions to be applicable to a broad audience, but asking whether a specific combination of hardware is suitable is much too localized to your situation, sorry. See also the part in the [FAQ] about shopping recommendations, as well as: [QoTW: How should I choose Hardware?](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/06/20/qotw-how-should-i-choose-hardware/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems legit.

On the surface at least, all these components appear to be supported and will function together. It's unlikely that with new components you'll run in to serious issues - I've found while building systems that it's become a lot less of a problem in recent years. As long as the board supports the components, you'll be fine.

The only thing I would suggest is that you might want to consider a stronger power supply than 500W. Your graphics card alone is capable of pulling 225W, similar to mine, and 500W wasn't enough to make it happy in my system, so I sprung for an 800W one.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It brings me to another question, can I fit 2.5cm HDDs in a desktop PC?

Comment: 2.5 inch, and it depends on your chassis. Usually desktop hard drives are 3.5 inch, but you can get "adapters" to make a smaller drive fit in a bigger bay. I have some here, they weren't exactly expensive, but make sure they're designed to adjust the sizes you have (ie 2.5 in drive, 3.5 in bay, for example).